# Subset data (columns) based on quantiles of column sums

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

is there a smart way to select columns from a dataframe based on quantiles of columns sums?  For example, only select columns from the dataframe whose column sum is in the first quantile.  I can subset data based column sums and I can calculate quantiles of column sums, but is there a way good way to combine theses?  Thanks.

```
# e.g. subset data - select columns whose column sums are less than 5
mydata <- mydata[,colSums(mydata) < 5]

# e.g create quantiles on colSums
mydata_cs <- colSums(mydata)
quart.mydata_cs <- quantile(mydata_cs,probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25))
```

Comment: Replace `5` by `quart.mydata_cs` , where `quart.mydata_cs = quantile(mydata_cs, probs = 0.25)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your `mydata_cs`, the following should work

```
mydata.firstquart <- mydata[,mydata_cs < quantile(mydata_cs,0.25)]
```

Based on your first line of code, I'm assuming by "first quartile" you mean lowest quartile. If you want the highest quartile, just change that to

```
mydata.firstquart <- mydata[,mydata_cs > quantile(mydata_cs,0.75)]
```

You may also want to use `<=` or `>=` rather than `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
 y <- c(4,6,9,2,9)
 df <- data.frame(x,y)
 q <-  quantile(colSums(df),probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25))
 df[,colSums(df) < q[2] ,drop=FALSE]
```